# Условие с динамическим значением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать условие, если переменная `$date` соответствует шаблону `12 december 2015 12:33:11`. Числа, естественно, любые. Пробовал с помощью регулярных выражений, не получилось что-то.

Comment: А какие регулярные выражения пробовали?

Comment: то есть вы хотите проверить что в переменной именно дата находится?

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю, что автор хочет проверить именно формат записи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вариант не подходит?

`preg_match('/^\d{1,2} [a-z]+ \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$/i', $date)`

Comment: вот тут `[a-z]+` наверное можно `?` добавить

Comment: а зачем? разве `[a-z]+` не поймает любой набор букв?

Comment: поймает, поймает, возможно в данном случае разницы нет :)

Comment: Что вы так `{}` любите, `\d\d?` как то проще выглядит и обычно время все таки с ведущими нулями при таком формате бывает

Comment: @Mike, а что плохого в `{}` ? :-D

Comment: @Grundy плохого конечно ничего, просто читабельность меньше и выражение длиннее. Хотя возможно это из разряда "основано на мнениях" :)

Comment: Ну эта любовь субъективна :) День вполне может быть без ведущего нуля. Да и час тоже... если использовать 12-часовую систему

Comment: При 12 часовой системе функции вывода времени дополняют 1 цифру часа пробелом, так что там может оказаться пробел перед временем и кстати перед числом то же

Answer (score 4):

Для полной проверки даты на корректность, а не только по примерному формату используйте функцию `strptime`. Но проверка названия месяца в ней зависит от текущей локали. Как дополнительный бонус вы получаете дату/время в виде массива, разобранного на компоненты и в числовом виде. Если дата не соответствует шаблону, функция возвращает `FALSE`

```
<?php
$date="2 november 2015 2:33:11";
$dtarr=strptime($date, '%d %B %Y %T');
if(is_array($dtarr))
 {
  print "Дата корректна:\n";
  print_r($dtarr);
 }
else print "Некорректная дата";

?>
```